# How not to build a library if it is not used?

Tags: cmake

I use cmake and create a library through the function:

```
add_library(network_transport)
```

I add the library via the function:

```
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} network_transport)
```

I noticed that if you remove target_link_libraries, the library is still assembled when completely reassembled. Is it possible to skip this if it (the library) is not used in this assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` to... exclude target from building when building them all.

```
add_library(network_transport EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

Or typically with third-party libraries:

```
add_subdirectory(dir/with/network_transport EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```